# Effect of frequency division on a signal's spectrum?

Tags: fourier

I am constantly on the lookout for effective yet inexpensive means to generate SSB signals. Analog Devices' LTC5598 Direct Quadrature Modulator turns baseband analog I/Q signals into RF from 5MHz to 1.6GHz. Sadly, for my purposes, the performance falls off dramatically below 5MHz.

What would happen, theoretically, if the output of the LTC5598 could be processed through some frequency-dividing means to cover lower frequencies? Would the spectrum of the modulation be preserved, distorted or destroyed? I would appreciate a reference outlining the Fourier analysis of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just divide the frequency of an arbitrary signal. Think about this pathological case:

Imagine you have an RF signal at 100MHz occupying a bandwidth of 1MHz. What happens if you frequency "divide" it down to 100kHz? You can't, because then you wouldn't have enough bandwidth at that center frequency.

You can however use frequency shifting, but that's basically what a quadrature modulator does.

So if you tried to use frequency shifting, you'd need a quadrature modulator after the output of the LTC5598, so that's not exactly productive.

I suggest you get a different quadrature modulator, or (especially since your CF is low), use direct digital upconversion by just blasting the signal with a fast DAC. A 10MHz DAC can pump out 0-5MHz, so use something like that.

Comment: +1 for using pathological case

Comment: While your conclusion is correct, your logic is mistaken.  You most certainly *can* (in the theoretical sense) divide a signal, but you'll divide its occupied bandwidth too.  The result for something like SSB would be the same as if you applied the division to the audio frequency - ie, useless for voice.  It could work for some data stream if the fact that this was going to be done was planned in from the beginning, however.

Comment: In terms of shifting the output of the chip, that would probably *not* need to be done with a quadrature (ie image reject) mixer, as the asker is going to be targeting something like the 80 or 160 meter ham band, meaning the shift will be large enough that they can easily remove the images with filters that they would need to have anyway.

Comment: I'd like to see the theoretical formulation for *why* it shouldn't work, because there might be an inexpensive method to "pre-distort" the input to produce an undistorted result.

Comment: Well, even if there was, there's not actually a way to "divide" a signal in the frequency domain. You can shift it (mixing), but not divide it. edit: at least not an arbitrary one with regular circuit elements

Comment: @BrianK1LI - if you were going to divide the RF by two, you'd need to first multiply your audio input by two.   That sounds like some fun DSP... it actually *is* done, in for example dance DJ players that can adjust tempo independently of pitch - you can usually hear artifacts but it's almost good enough for music and would be fine for voice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time_stretching_and_pitch_scaling yup, this is not an easy problem

Comment: @hatsunearu - sure there is.  For a signal without amplitude information, you just feed it through a toggle flipflop.   Things get more complex if you need (as the asker would) to maintain linearity.

Comment: Yeah, I editted in my caveat shortly after :P

Comment: As an experiment, I passed two-tone SSB through a D-FF to divide the frequency by a factor of two. But, when I compare the spectrum of constant-amplitude two-tone SSB (normalized by dividing the two-tone SSB by its envelope) to the divide-by-2 version, they don't look the same, even after passing the squared output of the D-FF through a "reconstruction" filter. What I find confusing is that the divide-by-2 waveforms "look right" but the spectra are so different. This is why I'm looking for a theoretical, mathematical explanation.

Comment: @BrianK1LI try it on paper for one sinusoid at a time all the way back through the BFO to audio and it will be simple to see what happens (ie, 500 Hz -> 5000500 Hz -> 2500250 Hz -> 250 Hz, 1000 Hz -> 5001000 Hz -> 2500500 Hz -> 500 Hz)  You are likely getting confused by *implementation* issues, in particular as a flip-flop divider is not *linear* with respect to amplitude it will also be functioning as a mixer introducing severe intermodulation distortion, which is what people are typically trying to measure with a two tone test...

Answer (score 0):

The output of a divider will be constant amplitude.

That means whatever signal you generate should be possible with FM or phase modulation only. While you can generate surprisingly complicated spectra with FM only (for instance see US patent 5170486), conventional SSB requires amplitude and phase modulation, so cannot be done with a divider. You may be able to, following the above patent, define a 'good' SSB channel, and a 'rubbish' channel which contains the artifacts caused by using phase modulation only. With SSB, you tend to tune to only one channel at a time, so the receiver would separate the two.

Once you've defined your output phase modulation profile, it's then trivial to multiply that up and use to program your 5598. Make it generate a constant amplitude, so you'll have a nice signal to clock the divider with.

However, that's all quite hard work, and you'd be far better using a modulator with a lower carrier frequency.

Comment: I can work with a constant-amplitude signal. I found in my experiment that the spectrum of a two-tone SSB signal that is "normalized" to constant amplitude through division by the envelope is identical to the same input signal "digitized" by passing it through a buffer circuit (except for the addition of harmonics, of course). Passing the digitized signal through a FF divider produces a signal that appears to be the input signal at half the frequency - i.e., the zero crossings appear at the expected times - but the spectrum isn't simply the input spectrum divided by two in frequency.

Comment: @BrianK1LI Yes, it isn't. All the people that have commented saying the modulation will be divided by two in frequency clearly haven't done the experiment. The modulation stays at the same frequency, but the phase deviation, that is the modulation depth, is divided by 2, so drops in amplitude by 6dBs, at the same frequency offset.